# Deploy two different application on one ip address?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, tomcat, redirect

I have wrote two web-site and want to deploy them on one server (Windows Server 2016 or Linux Ubuntu).

My tomcat configure (Spring Boot 3 + Java 17)

```
@Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {@Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        connector.findSslHostConfigs();
        return connector;
    }
```

For one web-site this configure work is perfect. I enter localhost (or domain) and open my web-site.

But what i must do for second web-site.
if my port 80 and 443 is busy, and if i write set.port 90 i must enter localhost:90.

I hope you undersant my problem, and can help me or give some materail that can hepl me with that. thx

```
connector.setPort(80);
connector.setRedirectPort(443);
```

How solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

let me guess your expects.

To deploy two Spring Boot applications on the same server with different ports, you'll need to configure each application's embedded Tomcat server to use a unique port. Additionally, you'll need to configure the second application's Tomcat server to listen on a different port (e.g., 90) if port 80 is already in use.

There is two steps to achieve your goal.

1. use spring properties
2. Add Java vm options (this is optional step ,if you configurate the application port correct)

##### use spring properties

Modify the `application.properties` or YAML file:

You can define the server port for each application in the application.properties or application.yml file. For example:

```
##### For the first application
server.port=80
```

###### For the second application

```
server.port=90
```

In your Spring Boot application's configuration class where you define the ServletWebServerFactory, you can set the port dynamically based on a property value. Here's how you can modify your configuration class:

There is no  minimum executable demo ,so  i create one with maybe  difference dependency , you can take reference;

```java
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TomcatCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int serverPort;

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(serverPort); // Use the port defined in application.properties
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        connector.findSslHostConfigs();
        return connector;
    }
}
```

This way, each application will read the server.port property from its respective application.properties file and listen on the specified port.

Run each application with its respective configuration:

#### Add Java vm options

Make sure to run each application with its unique port configuration. For example, for the first application:

```bash
java -jar your-first-application.jar
```

And for the second application:

```bash
java -jar -Dserver.port=90 your-second-application.jar
```

With these modifications, each of your Spring Boot applications will be able to run on different ports, allowing you to deploy them on the same server without conflicts.

For more detail  ,you can take a reference here [spring-user-@value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/value-annotations.html#page-title)